# Not sure why columns return zero

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, iterator

it is my first week trying to use python. You will note by my question that I'm beginner and probably this is a very stupid question.

I'm trying to use google trends and improve the code to get some automated results. I have two codes, the first one is working perfect. In the second one I decided to create a list in a .txt file. It's reading the list, but for some reason the google trend is returning data only for the first keyword (it fills with zero the followings columns).

Code 1 - works fine

```
import pytrends
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, time

pytrend = TrendReq()

searches = ['detox', 'water fasting', 'benefits of fasting', 'fasting benefits',
'acidic', 'water diet', 'ozone therapy', 'colon hydrotherapy', 'water fast']

groupkeywords = list(zip(*[iter(searches)]*1))
groupkeywords = [list(x) for x in groupkeywords]

dicti = {}
i = 1
for trending in groupkeywords:
    pytrend.build_payload(trending, timeframe = 'today 3-m', geo = 'GB')
    dicti[i] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
    i+=1

result = pd.concat(dicti, axis=1)
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
result = result.drop('isPartial', axis = 1)
result.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
print(result)
```

Code 2 - Does not work. I've created a txt file "test" in the same folder as the code.

This is the 2 code:

```
import pytrends
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
import sys
from datetime import datetime, date, time

pytrend = TrendReq()

file = open('test.txt','r')
f = file.readlines()
file.close()

searches = []
for line in f:
    searches.append(line.strip())
    
groupkeywords = list(zip(*[iter(searches)]*len(searches)))
groupkeywords = [list(x) for x in groupkeywords]

dicti = {}
i = 1
for trending in groupkeywords:
    pytrend.build_payload(trending, timeframe = 'today 3-m', geo = 'GB')
    dicti[i] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
    i+=1

result = pd.concat(dicti, axis=1)
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
result = result.drop('isPartial', axis = 1)
result.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
print(result)
```

After trying a lot of different things, I realized that even the first code does not work when I change words (in the searches). The example bellow did not work:

```
searches = ['Casillero del Diablo', 'Don Melchor', 'Marques de Casa Concha', 'CdD Reserva Especial', 'Cono Sur Organico']
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the question, the first thing that we see is that you don't need to provide the text in '' in the text file.

My input :

```
detox,
water fasting,
benefits of fasting,
fasting benefits,
acidic,
water diet,
ozone therapy,
colon hydrotherapy,
water fast
```

Secondly, you need to split the line on the delimiter and append it to the searches.

```
searches = []
for line in f:
    searches.append(line.split(',')[0])
```

This is ensure the searches array as desired :

Output :

```
Out[13]: 
['detox',
 'water fasting',
 'benefits of fasting',
 'fasting benefits',
 'acidic',
 'water diet',
 'ozone therapy',
 'colon hydrotherapy',
 'water fast']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.
I did the modifications but it didn't work.
I'm still getting zeros in the others columns that are not the first one.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: I didn’t get you when you said “I am still getting zeroes in the other columns that are not the first one”. Could you explain it more?

Comment: Sure, I will print the output and paste it here (in the main question)

Comment: @Digs I am confused by your question. What is it that you are trying to achieve?